# WPF - Load image stored in another dll

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I have a dll with the generic tools for my game named GameTools. In there I also have a folder with some images, they are set to Embedded Resource (I want them to carry with the dll transparently). Those images represent the sides of dices. and they should be loaded into a public List. Something like this:

```
public List<ImageSource> faceImages = new List<ImageSource>();
public void init()
{
    //there is a known set of images, so I can load them one by one
    faceImages.add(new BitmapImage(new Uri("/GameTools;component/Images/face1.png", UriKind.Relative)););
    faceImages.add(new BitmapImage(new Uri("/GameTools;component/Images/face2.png", UriKind.Relative)););
    ...
}
```

Then I have a WPF component that is the dice itself (named `Dice`), that uses a reference to the GameTools.

In the `dice` I have an image (`img`) and a function to "roll the dice". that should look something like:

```
public void roll()
{
    int face = random.Next(0,6);
    img.Source = LOAD_THE_REFERENCE(face);
}
```

Does anyone how to code this LOAD_THE_REFERENCE? or maybe the problem is in the way I "import" the images into the GameTools. Not sure, plenty of different solutions on the internet that don't really helped me out so far. Can anyone help here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set the Build Action of the image files to **Resource** and access them by full [Resource File Pack URIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.100).aspx#Resource_File_Pack_URIs___Local_Assembly):

```
var bitmap = new BitmapImage(
    new Uri("pack://application:,,,/GameTools;component/Images/face1.png"));
```

Comment: this is for loading, or..  for accessing from the other dll?

Comment: `GameTools` is the name of the assembly that contains the image resources. The images can then be loaded by an application that references the GameTools assembly via pack URIs. You could of course also put the loading code in a method of some class in GameTools.